# install open icon library in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: installation, 10.04, icons, downloads, libraries

I download open icon library from http://openiconlibrary.sourceforge.net/ so, how can i install it in ubuntu 10.04??

Comment: Could you tell me what is your purpose of installing the library and where exactly are trying to use/implement it? I am trying to find a solution for it, if you could provide us more details it will help us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check with the installation notes provided with download, other wise most of the time these work fine.

If you have downloaded the `.tar.bz2` file, then first place(copy) it where you want to extract, for example on desktop.

Then extract the file by right clicking on the file and select " Extract Here", or from the terminal by giving the command

```
$ tar xjf file.tar.bz2
```

Now move in to the folder created, for example

```
$ cd /home/yourusername/Desktop/folder name

$ ./configure

$ make

$ make install
```

Use `sudo` where ever it says permissions denied.

Comment: i write ./configure but i had an error: bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: are you in the directory which you have extracted? can you post the exact error message.

Comment: yes i am, ok it is look like this :

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$  cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/open_icon_library-devel
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Desktop/open_icon_library-devel$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~/Desktop/open_icon_library-devel$